# How to determine proper size of ignite thread pool?

Tags: ignite

In my ignite cluster, there are two server mode node consisting data grid and eight client mode node consisting compute grid.

And about 40 tasks are invoked at compute grid every 20~30 seconds(usually tasks are terminated in 20 seconds.) and logs are stored at ignite cache(persistence true).

That tasks are invoked by cache event(EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_PUT) occured from 'default' cache when task information is put in by memcached client at out of ignite cluster.

After memcached client add task info, it does polling task info status every 2 seconds(get status info from 'default' cache that it has put) and when status changed to 'termination', client terminates.

Below is my thread pool setting.

**pool:

rebalanceThreadPoolSize: 4

publicThreadPoolSize: 256

systemThreadPoolSize: 32

dataStreamerThreadPoolSize: 16

stripedPoolSize: 16**


My server has 24 cores and 32GB memory.

Is my thread pool size setting is proper?

I often face thread starvation messages like 'Possible thread pool starvation detected (no task completed in last 30000ms, is system(or public rarely) thread pool size large enough?)'

Is there anyone who could advise something?

Comment: We can't say without looking at your thread dumps taken at the moment of "possible thread pool starvation". Please send them to Ignite users list.

Comment: Note that decreasing stripedPoolSize to less than # of cores is NOT recommended. It's an important pool.

Comment: @alamar thanks, I'll try adjust stripedPoolSize first.